# Firebase .indexOn how it works?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

If I for example have:

```
users: {
    userId1: {
        email: "email1"
    },
    userId2: {
        email: "email2"
    }
}
```

If I want to figure out if a new certain email I want to add to my users tree exists or not.
I would expect the complexity to be linear to the amount of data in the users tree. Like O(n)?

If I have the rule:

```
"users": {
    ".indexOn": ["email"]
}
```

What is it Firebase is doing exactly? Does it turn into something like O(1)?